# Clone div with embeded divs (row-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have code which works but only partially.
It is cloning main div with embedded divs (using Bootstrap row class). What I want to achieve is have "Remove author" button hidden at the start but after cloning it will become active and I will be able to remove entry. At the moment I don't know how to activate remove button.
Here is a code:

```
<div id="author1" class="clonedInput">
<p id="author" name="author" class="label1">Author</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_title textboxstyle" required="">
        <p id="help-block-title" name="help-block-title" for="title" class="help-block-title">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn textboxstyle" required="">
        <p id="help-block-fn" name="help-block-fn" for="fn" class="help-block-fn">First Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_ln textboxstyle" required="">
        <p id="help-block-ln" name="help-block-ln" for="ln" class="help-block-ln">Last Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="abc@example.com" class="input_email textboxstyle" required="">
        <p id="help-block-email" name="help-block-email" for="email" class="help-block-email">Email</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
        <input id="checkbox" name="contact" type="checkbox" value="YES">
        <p id="help-block-checkbox" name="help-block-checkbox" for="checkbox" class="help-block-checkbox">Contact</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
        <button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-info" >Add author</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
        <button id="btnDel" name="btnDel" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" hidden="true">Remove author</button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
            newElem = $('#author' + num).clone().attr('id', 'author' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); 

        // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

    /*  This is where we manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new, cloned element
        Below are examples of what forms elements you can clone, but not the only ones.
        There are 2 basic structures below: one for an H2, and one for form elements.
        To make more, you can copy the one for form elements and simply update the classes for its label and input.
        Keep in mind that the .val() method is what clears the element when it gets cloned. Radio and checkboxes need .val([]) instead of .val('').
    */
        // <p> - section
        newElem.find('.label1').attr('id', 'author_' + 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'author_' + 'ID' + newNum).html('Author' + newNum);

        // Title - select
        newElem.find('.input_title').attr('id', 'title' + 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'title' + 'ID' + newNum).val('');

        // First name - text
        newElem.find('.input_fn').attr('id', 'first_name_' + 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'first_name_' + 'ID' + newNum).val('');

        // Last name - text
        newElem.find('.input_ln').attr('id', 'last_name_' + 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'last_name_' + 'ID' + newNum).val('');

        // Email - text
        newElem.find('.input_email').attr('id', 'email_address_' + 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'email_address_' + 'ID' + newNum).val('');

      // Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#author' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

    // Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    // Right now you can only add 4 sections, for a total of 5. Change '5' below to the max number of sections you want to allow.
        if (newNum == 5)
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit"); // value here updates the text in the 'add' button when the limit is reached 
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
    // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
            {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
                // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#entry' + num).slideDown('slow', function () {$(this).remove();
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                    if (num -1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");});
            }
        return false; // Removes the last section you added
    });
    // Enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
    // Disable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qcpo2a47/11/

Comment: It's going to be tough if the `id` attributes are significant; removing an author from the middle of the list could create a gap.

Comment: Yes, ID attributes are significant in this case. I thought it might be tough but still hope that someone is able to share some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried [something,updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1558p7n/)

```
$(document).on('click','[name="btnDel"]',function() {

if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone.")) {

  var num = $('.clonedInput').index();
  var count=$('.clonedInput').length;



    if (count - 1 === 1)
    {
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
    }
      else{
        $(this).parents('.clonedInput').remove();
         $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');
      }





}
return false;   });
```

I tried attaching all the events with`on` handler, check it out if it works for you.good luck.

Comment: Amazing, that works however there is small glitch. with this code I am able to remove all author but I need to have always one. So I need to protect it somehow. Also any idea how I can use "add author" button except of the first one. it seems to be that I am able to add authors only with first add button

Comment: i have updated the answer and it is protecting the last author, one more thing, kindly point out the glitch i want to improve my skills :)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, I am learning so not really experienced. However do you think you could help further? do you think that there is an option to not have "remove author" button in first instance but it would appear after adding an author? as I said I am learning so any help is great. thank you

Comment: Looks like you know what to do. So please let me ask you something else. When I add extra author, remove button is appearing only next first author. Is there any chance that it will appear only next to duplicated authors but not the first one? And the other thing is, when I remove duplicated authors and only first one remains, it will not duplicate it anymore. Instead it will display remove author button which will allow me to remove first author. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome mate, you want delete button on the last cloned div or on every div excluding first one?

Comment: On the last cloned div if possible. So that way I can remove last added author.

Comment: I wish I could just do it myself. your help is great. it is almost exactly what I need. Remove button works just perfect! Last thing is. Once I have 5 authors, first "add author" button becomes disabled however another "add author" buttons can still add author. Any chance to have all 5 "add author" buttons disabled once total count is 5. And once additional authors are removed, first "add author" becomes enabled?  Thank you

Comment: Or might be better if "add author" and "remove author" buttons were displayed only next to last cloned div and then once it reaches total count 5 "add author" would become disabled? On click "remove author" and reaching only first author there would be again only "add author" button. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: we are here to help only mate but you should practice more, it is very easy stuff, good luck with that and that thing you asked for is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/57v0d5cf/)

Comment: if you want to put add author or remove author next to last cloned div then it would be a lot easier than this, try this i believe you can do it yourself.

Comment: thank you for all your help. I am trying to find some free time to practice and improve. however if I'm stuck you guys are always helpful. Also any chance to send a link for your last post (having add and remove button next to last cloned div) Again, much appreciated all your help

Comment: yes, have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sdeg4nps/), i am hoping for a day when you will help out someone who is stuck at some code, cheers mate :)

Comment: I hope too, that is why I want to learn so to be able to help in the future.

Comment: Thank you again, you are star!

Comment: you are welcome friend, mark the answer if it helped you